# Facing problem while importing org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope

Tags: android, web-services, importerror

Am working with web service. Got some sample code from internet. Got some error while importing

```
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.AndroidHttpTransport;
```

[image: error]

Not able to proceed .Can any one help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you havnt added the **ksoap** jar file in your project, add library first

get it from **[HERE](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/)** or http://sourceforge.net/projects/ksoap2/

Answer (score 0):

Steps to add Ksoap .jar file in Project:
Right Click on Project --> Select PROPERTIES --> Click on JAVA BUILDPATH -->
select LIBRARIES --> click on ADD EXTERNAL JARS --> select JAR file from storage 
path and finally click OK