# I was learning xml parser following the android guide, but the sample project prompts error, what could be the reason?

Tags: android, xml, parsing

here is the link http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html , the sample code is at the right for downloading.

**I am using wi-fi connection, some ppl suggest disable the LAN card, and i did so, still exceptions... and all the project related to read xml do not work on my emulator.**

**it prompt me this error**

```
10-11 08:41:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(825): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-11 08:41:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(825): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.networkusage/com.example.networkusage.NetworkActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.networkusage.NetworkActivity
10-11 08:41:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
10-11 08:41:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
10-11 08:41:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
10-11 08:41:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
10-11 08:41:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-11 08:41:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-11 08:41:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-11 08:41:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-11 08:41:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-11 08:41:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-11 08:41:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-11 08:41:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-11 08:41:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(825): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.networkusage.NetworkActivity
10-11 08:41:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
10-11 08:41:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
10-11 08:41:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
10-11 08:41:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
10-11 08:41:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
10-11 08:41:43.169: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: you can use this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441228/facing-problem-while-importing-org-ksoap2-soapenvelope

Comment: i dont have errors, but when i run it, the exception prompt. so, not the same problem

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:-
I donwloaded and imported the sample to Eclipse. In order to make it run I had to edit the android manifest so it read

```
<activity
            <!-- note removed all but simple name from android:name -->
            android:name="NetworkActivity" 
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <!-- more stuff -->
</activity>
```

---

It seems that you need to add com.example.networkusage.NetworkActivity to the AndroidManifest

```
        <activity 
            android:name="com.example.networkusage.NetworkActivity"
        </activity>
```

---

There's also an issue with the developer docs from Google that your manifest shouldn't really have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

at the top. At least Eclipse always complains for me if I include it. If you've copied that line in from the docs it's worth taking it out. I don't think that's the problem based on the Exception posted but...

Comment: Hi, this line is already included in the manifest if you take a closer look.

Comment: unless I've had way too much caffeine today your android manifest isn't in the question :-). That exception is telling you that the application can't find the Activity class. Could you add the manifest and activity as you've implemented them?

Comment: on the right side there is the sample code. could you download it and take a look?